# Will the 100 DAO = 1.5 ETH ratio change in the future after the creation phase ?

Tags: the-dao, dao, dao-hub

Will the ratio between DAO and ETH ever change like ETH/USD after the creation phase ..... like after a couple of years ?

Answer (score 4):

After the creation phase, no new tokens can be issued - so the exchange rate depends entirely on what people selling their DAO tokens price them at, and what people buying them are willing to pay.

Comment: what I dont understand is that if the ratio changes then how does the [return of the ETH](https://daohub.org/creation.html) is still proportional to the initial investment ?  - Any DAO Token Holder can - at anytime - submit a Proposal to request the ETH they are entitled to, proportionally to the number of DAO tokens they hold.
 - At any time, the DAO Token Holder may retrieve their proportional amount of ETH not already committed to a Proposal.

Comment: @goutham That sounds like a separate question.